# SQLite, AsyncTask. Расшифровка stack trace

Tags: android, sqlite, android-asynctask, stacktrace

Иногда возникает ошибка (менее чем на 1% устройств). Не совсем понятно, что происходит.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException:
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done (AsyncTask.java:325)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion (FutureTask.java:354)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException (FutureTask.java:223)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:242)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run (AsyncTask.java:243)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:761)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.acquireReference (SQLiteClosable.java:55)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory (SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery (SQLiteDatabase.java:1257)
at com.dev.z.myapp.db.DataBase.createTable (DataBase.java)
or .delete (DataBase.java)
or .restore (DataBase.java)
or .selectAll (DataBase.java)
at com.dev.z.myapp.ui_main.FragmentMain$1.doInBackground (FragmentMain.java)
or .onPostExecute (FragmentMain.java)
at com.dev.z.myapp.ui_main.FragmentMain$1.doInBackground (FragmentMain.java)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call (AsyncTask.java:305)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run (AsyncTask.java:243)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:761)
```

AsyncTask примерно такой:

```
new AsyncTask<CurNameAndSort, Void, ArrayList<DataModel>>(){
    @Override
    protected ArrayList<DataModel> doInBackground(CurNameAndSort... curNameAndSorts) {
        ArrayList<DataModel> data = DataBase.selectAll (curNameAndSorts[0].getCurrentName (), curNameAndSorts[0].getSort());
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<DataModel> data) {
        adapter.setDataModels(data);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}.execute(new CurNameAndSort(currentName, sort));
```

Comment: Приведи код AsyncTask

Comment: Посмотрите здесь https://stackoverflow.com/a/2485145